# Setting launch options for Xterm

Tags: settings, xterm

I would like to start Xterm terminal with "Always on Top" option enabled rather than right-clicking and setting it on manually each time. How can I do it ?

Comment: Also see this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180797